# How to plot a chart with both primary and secondary axis in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I want to draw a mschart with both primary and secondary Y-Axis and a common X-axis. Here are the possible duplicates but I didn't find the explanation I was looking for:

[Charts multi type and secondary Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180606/charts-multi-type-and-secondary-y-axis)

[MS Chart Control Two Y Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458791/ms-chart-control-two-y-axis)

I need some help on how to draw such a chart using `MSChart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ChartArea chartarea = new ChartArea();

Series Memory = new Series();

RepeatsMemoryPlot.Series.Add(Memory);

//Add points to series Memory

Memory.Points.AddXY(a, b);

Series Time = new Series();

RepeatsMemoryPlot.Series.Add(Time);

Time.ChartArea = Memory.ChartArea;

Time.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;


//Add Points to time series
Time.Points.AddXY(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ChartArea, you select Axis then Secondary Y(values) axis
And change the Enabled from Auto to True

The second Axis will show